# MySql Table Relationship

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon everyone, my question is:

I currently have 3 tables in the database.

The tables:

- investors_positive (client_cod, net_cliente, advisor_cod)
- investors_clients_balance (client_cod, client_name)
- investors_base_advisors (advisor_cod, advisor_name)

I would like to get the following columns as a result of the sql query:

- customer_code
- customer_name
- net_client
- advisor_name

The result of the select must contain all the customer codes of the column (customer_cod) of the table (investors_positivador).

What happens is that I can get the information (client_cod, client_name, net_cliente), but adviser_name I can't, as I would have to reference the adviser_cod column (investors_positivador) to the adviser_name column (investors_base_assessores)

Below is the command I got and managed to get all the data (with the exception of the name_assessor):

```
SELECT investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_positivador.net_em_m, 
    investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente
FROM investors_positivador 
INNER JOIN investors_saldo_financeiro 
    ON investors_positivador.cod_cliente = investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente
```

I tried:

```
SELECT investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente, investors_base_assessores.cod_assessor 
FROM investors_positivador 
INNER JOIN investors_saldo_financeiro 
    ON investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente = investors_positivador.cod_cliente 
INNER JOIN investors_base_assessores 
    ON investors_base_assessores.cod_assessor = investors_positivador.cod_assessor
```

Comment: This question is very confusing, because you keep changing the names of tables and columns. Is `assessor_cod` supposed to be `advisor_cod`?

Comment: Just add a second `INNER JOIN` to the third table.

Comment: I've already tried to add a second INNER JOIN, but the query crashes when I'm going to do it with both

Comment: Show what you tried, then we'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: I tried:

SELECT investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente, investors_base_assessores.nome_assessor
FROM 
investors_positivador
INNER JOIN investors_saldo_financeiro ON investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente = investors_positivador.cod_cliente
INNER JOIN investors_base_assessores ON investors_base_assessores.cod_assessor = investors_positivador.cod_assessor

Comment: It shouldn't crash, but you should select `investors_base_assessores.nome_assessor` to get the name.

Comment: Correction:

SELECT investors_positivador.cod_cliente, investors_saldo_financeiro.nome_cliente, investors_base_assessores.nome_assessor, investors_base_assessores.nome_investor
FROM 
investors_positivador
INNER JOIN investors_saldo_financeiro ON investors_saldo_financeiro.cod_cliente = investors_positivador.cod_cliente
INNER JOIN investors_base_assessores ON investors_base_assessores.cod_assessor = investors_positivador.cod_assessor

Comment: I think the query takes a long time to run, and ends up crashing. In cases where I use LIMIT 5, it manages to return the 5 data correctly.

Comment: Please stop putting code in comments. Put it in the question, so you can format it readably. See how I edited the question the last time.

Comment: Make sure the `cod_XXX` columns are all indexed.